# why launching activity getting stop?(Image upload activity)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to make a project but i am finding some problem ! i used debugger but cant find the problem of run time error ! please debugger error is given below -

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main . 
>        Process: com.example.abed.smit, PID: 24486
>                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abed.smit/com.example.abed.smit.PrescriptionUpload}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.abed.smit.PrescriptionUpload cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6368)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
>                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.abed.smit.PrescriptionUpload cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
>                             at com.example.abed.smit.PrescriptionUpload.onCreate(PrescriptionUpload.java:33)
>                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
>                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6368) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

AND the code of my ***activity*** is given below:

```
package com.example.abed.smit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PrescriptionUpload extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 234;
private ImageView imageView;
private Button buttonchoose, buttonUpload;

private Uri filepath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prescription_upload);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    buttonchoose = findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

    buttonchoose.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    buttonchoose.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
}


private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SELECT AN IMAGE"),     PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)    {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data != null
            && data.getData() != null) {
        filepath = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filepath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonchoose) {
        showFileChooser();

    } else if (view == buttonUpload) {

    }
}


}
```

Comment: ` buttonchoose.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this)` your `PrescriptionUpload` is not implementing `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: your `PrescriptionUpload` is not a `View.OnClickListener`. You can't cast it.

Comment: tnx sir ! its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not cast a activity to Listener interface

You need to implements `View.OnClickListener` in your  `PrescriptionUpload` Activity

```
public class PrescriptionUpload extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener
```

Than use like this

```
buttonchoose.setOnClickListener( this);
buttonchoose.setOnClickListener( this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting your current activity to a Listener class. That won't work given your code

`buttonchoose.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);`

This cast expects `this` to be of type View.OnClickListener or have the `this` class (PrescriptionUpload) implement that interface.

What you probably want is

`public class YourActivity implements View.OnClickListener`